# Why is the demon Hiraṇyakaśipu addressed with 'Shri' in the Srimad Bhagwatam?

Tags: vaishnavism, bhagavata-purana, gaudiya-vaishnavism, iskcon, madhwa

Why is the demon Hiraṇyakaśipu addressed with 'Shri' in the Srimad Bhagwatam?

For instance, this verse from Srimad Bhagwatam Canto 7 Chapter 8 Verse 11:
श्रीहिरण्यकशिपुरुवाच
व्यक्तं त्वं मर्तुकामोऽसि योऽतिमात्रं विकत्थसे ।
मुमूर्षूणां हि मन्दात्मन् ननु स्युर्विक्लवा गिर: ॥ ११ ॥

As far as I am concerned, 'Shri' is used to denote Radharani or Mata Laxmi and is used as a symbol of auspiciousness and respect. Since Hiraṇyakaśipu is everything against auspiciousness, I am not able to comprehend why Suta Gosvāmī addresses Hiraṇyakaśipu with 'Shri' multiple times in the same canto.

Hare Krishna.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swami Prabhupada explains it in his [commentary](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/7/8/11/) like this:

> Although Hiraṇyakaśipu was a demon, he is described here by the added word śrī. Why? The answer is that fortunately he had such a great devotee son as Prahlāda Mahārāja. Thus although he was a demon, he would attain salvation and return home, back to Godhead.

On another note, [Gitapress version](https://archive.org/details/srimad-bhagavat-mahapuran-2-volume-set-sanskrit-hindi/Srimad%20Bhagavat%20Mahapuran%20Volume%201%20Sanskrit%20Hindi/page/n1339/mode/1up) doesn’t mention the word Shri in this verse:

> [image]